# iPhone X no smooth gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios11, iphone-x

I was experiencing problems with using gestures on the iPhone X simulator and thought this was a simulator problem, but on a real device the problem also exists.

For testing I've downloaded the MoveMe example made by Apple. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html)

And I created a video showing an iPhone 7 simulator and an iPhone X simulator where I try to drag the view. You will see on the iPhone 7 it's going as smooth as possible, but on the iPhone X it will stutter and it looks like it's lagging.

[Link to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKP-PsjrgEI)

This shows the problem I'm also experiencing in my own app, but I haven't found any other questions on StackOverflow mentioning this? Do any of you guys have experienced this??

Comment: Did you install MoveMe on a real device ? MoveMe works pretty well on my simulated iPhone X on my computer. You should always test performances using real devices.

Comment: @GaétanZ Sadly I don't have a physical iPhone X available for me at the moment.

Comment: I did, MoveMe is fine :)

Comment: Ok thanks for testing. Then I'll just have to get in deeper what is wrong with my app and put some more pressure on my boss that we really need an iPhone X for testing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> The simulator is running on your Mac, and the CPU in your Mac is most
>   likely much faster than the one in your iOS device. Conversely, the
>   GPU in your Mac is so different from the one in your iOS device that
>   the simulator has to emulate the device’s GPU entirely in software (on
>   the CPU), which means that GPU-bound operations usually run slower on
>   the simulator than they do on an iOS device, especially if you are
>   writing bespoke OpenGL code using CAEAGLLayer.
>
> This means that testing on the simulator gives a highly distorted view of performance. If an animation runs smoothly on the simulator, it may be terrible on a device. If it runs badly on the simulator, it may be fine on a device. You just can’t be sure.

from [https://www.amazon.com/iOS-Core-Animation-Advanced-Techniques-ebook/dp/B00EHJCORC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EHJCORC)

Comment: I completely agree on this one. But this doesn't explain the big difference I see on both simulators on the same device.

Comment: I guess : a iPhone X has more pixels, the GPU-bound operations are substantial so the emulated GPU is heavily loaded